# How to replace a child view with another in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an SPA written in AngularJS. The main page uses an ng-include attribute to determine which view to load. This is set in JavaScript when someone clicks on a menu which is contained within the main page. However, I've come across a situation where I need to load a different view by clicking a button within another view, essentially replacing it.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this and from what I've researched, I have to use $rootScope and either an $emit or $broadcast call in the child view and a $rootScope.$on method to detect this event.

The thing is, this doesn't seem to work. I have set my breakpoints and stepped through the code, but I always get this error:

Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2009-07-21T00%3A00%3A00

Here's the code in my parent page controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('viewChanged', function () {
    var menuItem = {
        template: 'customerOrders.html' // will be eventually dynamic
    };

    navigate(menuItem);
});

function navigate(menuItem) {
    $scope.activeMenuItem = menuItem;
}

<div data-ng-include="activeMenuItem.template"></div>
```

In the child page controller:

```
function changeSelectedView(viewTemplate) {
    $rootScope.$emit('selectedViewChanged', viewTemplate);
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here. How do I accomplish what I want, or is there a completely different way to do this?

Comment: your error seems to be irrelevant with your question though

Comment: I know, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: My bad, the date error is happening prior to my button click as there is a date field in the page that apparently doesn't allow a null value. Let me look at resolving that first.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ng-route` to work between views. check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Is that relevant when I'm not using routing?  This is a single page application.

Comment: @DesertFoxAZ yeah. `ng-route` doesn't change the page. It just changes the views with in the page. You can switch between multiple views in SPA by some input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the event name in the $emit function and in the $on function did not match, so I made that fix.

```
function navigateToNewTemplate(event, viewTemplate) {
    var menuItem = {
        template: buildTemplateUrl(viewTemplate)
    };

    navigate(menuItem);
}

$rootScope.$on('selectedViewChanged', navigateToNewTemplate);

function changeSelectedView(viewTemplate) {
    $rootScope.$emit('selectedViewChanged', viewTemplate);
}
```